# Split 2 checkboxes per row in GWT Panel

Tags: java, gwt, panel, uibinder

I am using [DisclosurePanel](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDisclosurePanel) in my GWT widget along with **UIBinder**.

In that Panel i am adding 3-4 checkboxes as shown below.

Test.ui.xml

```
<g:DisclosurePanel headerText="header" open="true" animationEnabled="true">             
<g:FlowPanel>
    <w1:Field name="uiAlert1"  fieldHelpText="HelpText">
        <g:CheckBox ui:field="Alert1" />
    </w1:Field>
    <w1:Field name="uiAlert2"  fieldHelpText="HelpText">
        <g:CheckBox ui:field="Alert2" />
    </w1:Field>
    <w1:Field name="uiAlert3"  fieldHelpText="HelpText">
        <g:CheckBox ui:field="Alert3" />
    </w1:Field>
</g:FlowPanel>              
</g:DisclosurePanel>
```

I want to split all the checkboxes in 2 checkbox per row.

How can i achieve this?
What element of GWT i should use inside my DisclosurePanel?

I have seen [HorizontalPanel](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwHorizontalPanel) and few others as well. But i am not sure what could be the best way to achieve this.

Thanks!

Comment: You may try a [`Grid`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Grid.html) with 2 columns and as many rows as you need.

Comment: I am able to achieve using `display: table` on FlowPanel & `display: table-cell` on child panels.